# ios kSecClassCertificate yields -25303

Tags: ios, security, certificate, keychain

I'm trying to store p12(pfx) certificate into keychain on ios
with code from keychainswift essentially, just the klass changed from password to certificate:

```
@discardableResult
open func setCertificate(_ value: Data, forKey key: String,
  withAccess access: KeychainSwiftAccessOptions? = nil) -> Bool {
  
  // The lock prevents the code to be run simultaneously
  // from multiple threads which may result in crashing
  lock.lock()
  defer { lock.unlock() }
  
  deleteNoLock(key) // Delete any existing key before saving it

  let accessible = access?.value ?? KeychainSwiftAccessOptions.defaultOption.value
    
  let prefixedKey = keyWithPrefix(key)
    
  var query: [String : Any] = [
    KeychainSwiftConstants.klass      : kSecClassCertificate,
    KeychainSwiftConstants.attrAccount : prefixedKey,
    KeychainSwiftConstants.valueData   : value,
    KeychainSwiftConstants.accessible  : accessible
  ]
    
  query = addAccessGroupWhenPresent(query)
  query = addSynchronizableIfRequired(query, addingItems: true)
  lastQueryParameters = query
  
  lastResultCode = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
  
  return lastResultCode == noErr
}
```

getting -25303 (invalid attribute that is)
Should I piecemeal store separetely identity, certificate chain and trust with different keys for this to work?

what's the difference between kSecClassCertificate and kSecClassPassword klasses of storage given that we
have keychains sandboxes and without GUI?
is this for forward compatibility with macos or something?

PS. Apple please attempt to find a tech writer who can fix the horrendous documentation around security framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the available attributes for a certificate are mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecclasscertificate). I believe your `attrAccount` is an invalid parameter and I feel, but I'm not sure that the `valueData` might be invalid. So remove at least the `attrAccount` and possibly the `valueData`.

Comment: which attribute should be used as a key instead of attrAccount?

Comment: There is an attribute called `kSecAttrLabel` which you could abuse, but I'd like to point out that a certificate should have a unique combination of issuer and serial number (`kSecAttrIssuer` and `kSecAttrSerialNumber` respectively). Maybe you can use those to identify the stored certificate